# ASA5520 CPU Utilization in 98%

Tags: networking

CPU utilization of The ASA 5520 in my company suddenly increased to 98% for 2 hour. In this time, I have checked the logs:

### Logs

```
Deny TCP reverse path check from 121.65.98.4 to 180.85.66.54 on interface inside
```

I canceled download in a PC, then the problem is resolved.

Could you please tel me what should I do that I will not faced with this problem for future.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic here, but can be asked on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the entire log message, and that's not necessarily the main cause of your CPU problems.

PIX/ASA messages each have a unique code, in this case it's `%PIX-1-106021` which you can look up in [the documentation (e.g for v6.3)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix63/system/message/pixemsgs.html#wp1052347).

Similarly if you look up [reverse path check](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/unicast-rpf.html) you will see that this problem is cause by either your firewall topology or routing being wrong, or a spoofed external IP address on the inside.

The trivial solutions (turn off verify with `no ip reverse-path` on an interface, or turn off that log message with `no logging message 106021`) are usually a bad idea.

This is probably a better starting point: [PIX/ASA: Monitor and Troubleshoot Performance Issues](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a008009491c.shtml)